# creating amd64 docker image on m1

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building docker images locally on a M1 Macbook using docker-compose and run it on google compute engine.
The third image ...flask-nginx_1 works fine - probably as docker indicates it being a amd64 build.

[image: Docker Desktop]

The next_js_1 image however crashes saying 'standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error'

Is there a way to specify this in the dockerfile to create an amd64 image?

Answer (score 2):

Most Docker commands support a `--platform` parameter, which sets the platform for the current invocation:

```bash
docker build --platform amd64 .
```

If you want a Dockerfile that *always* builds for a specific platform, you may specify the platform for an image in your Dockerfile using `FROM --platform`:

```
FROM --platform=amd64 debian
...
```

This overrides any command-line platform specification you might have.

In Compose, you can also specify the platform:

```yaml
services:
  my-svc:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: my-svc-image
```

It's quite possible to mix images from different platforms in the same compose file.

Comment: I added `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 [image]` to get this working on my M1